# Select columns from multiple tables where a column in each table is equal to a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

#### items

```
| item_id  | item_added_by_user_id     | item_name  |
| -------- | ------------------------- | ---------- |
| 1        | 23                        | item 1     |
| 2        | 23                        | item 2     |
| 3        | 24                        | item 3     |
```

#### extra_access

```
| item_id  | extra_user_id   |
| -------- | --------------- |
| 1        | 25              |
| 2        | 26              |
| 3        | 28              |
```

I want to check whether the current logged in user has access to edit this item. Users who have access are users under `item_added_by_user_id` and users under `extra_user_id` with the same `item_id`.

I read up on `JOIN`s and came up with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT items.item_added_by_user_id, ea.extra_user_id FROM items
INNER JOIN extra_access AS ea
ON items.item_id = ea.item_id AND
items.item_added_by_user_id=" . $SESSION['user_id'];
```

My 'logic' was that if any rows are returned, the user must have access, but this doesn't work.

What can I do to check whether the logged in user has access?

Comment: Please elaborate on what "doesn't work" *really* means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM items
WHERE item_added_by_user_id=$SESSION['user_id']
OR item_id IN(
  SELECT item_id 
  FROM extra_access 
  WHERE extra_user_id=$SESSION['user_id']
)
AND item_id=$idItem;
```

Comment: Nice! I hadn't thought of doing it this way. I'm accepting your answer because it's simpler (for me) because it doesn't have the complexities of `JOIN`s! :) thanks!

Comment: Yeah its also faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT items.item_added_by_user_id, ea.extra_user_id FROM items
INNER JOIN extra_access AS ea
ON items.item_id = ea.item_id
WHERE
items.item_added_by_user_id=" . $SESSION['user_id']
. " OR ea.extra_user_id=" . $SESSION['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think a `union all` query is appropriate:

```
select i.item_id
from items i
where item_added_by_user_id = $SESSION_USER
union all
select ea.item_id
from extra_access ea
where extra_user_id = $SESSION_USER;
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is quite the same than @Fuujin, but I only added the `$idItem` because in your question you mention "*I want to check whether the current logged in user has access to edit this item*" :

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct items.items_id
        FROM items
        LEFT JOIN extra_access AS ea ON items.item_id = ea.item_id 
        WHERE items.items_id = ".$idItem." 
        AND (items.item_added_by_user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." OR ea.extra_user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id'].")";
```

Moreover, I use LEFT join, not INNER, which could be a problem if items has no entry in `extra_access`.

If there is at least 1 result, then user has rights.

Comment: quick question; why `distinct`?